# How fetch the first record after every record that has specific attribute set in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I've got a table where some records have specific attribute set to non-null value. I'd like to fetch all records that are right after these records (when ordered by `created_at` column).

Here's sample data:

```
id | factor | created_at
 1 | NULL   | 2001-01-01
 2 | 1.2    | 2001-01-02
 3 | NULL   | 2001-01-03
 4 | NULL   | 2001-01-04
 5 | 0.9    | 2001-01-05
 6 | NULL   | 2001-01-06
 7 | 1.1    | 2001-01-07
 8 | NULL   | 2001-01-08
 9 | NULL   | 2001-01-09
10 | 1.1    | 2001-01-10
11 | NULL   | 2001-01-11
```

and so on. In this case I'd like to fetch records with IDs 3, 6, 8 and 11. Is it somehow possible in PostgreSQL 9.3? In the real app `ids` are not necessarily sequential - there's also `user_id` column and I'm fetching only records with the same `user_id` value. I've read a bit about `LEAD` window function that might be useful here, but I'm not sure how to use it in this case.

Comment: In your example does 'nil' mean null or is there an actual value stored as 'nil'?

Comment: Sorry about that, too much Ruby :) It's NULL.

Comment: Ah, gotchya. I think the lag function should do the trick (see my answer below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
select id, factor, created_at
  from (select id,
               factor,
               created_at,
               lag(factor, 1) over(order by created_at) as prev_factor
          from tbl
         order by created_at) x
 where factor is null
   and prev_factor is not null
```